There are 3 2-dimensional commutative algebras over reals, can we also say that there are 3 infinite-dimensional algebras with privileged properties?
We know that there are 3 2-dimensional commutative and associative unitial algebras over reals: complex numbers, split-complex numbers and dual numbers.
But I have a feeling that also there are 3 distinguished infinite-dimensional algebras.
To be more precise, there are 3 distinguished types of algebras because each one can be generalized to include more elements or restricted to include less. Each one can be generalized to uncountable number of dimensions or restricted to countably-infinite, but relations between elements of the algebras remain the same.
They are:

Those isomorphic to formal power series, transseries, Hardy fields and surreal numbers, depending on the degree of extension and generalization. They have a natural operation of derivation and an element denoted $\omega$ or $X$, corresponding to the germ at infinity of the identity function. Examples of countably-dimentional algebas of this type are the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and its (X)-adic completion, formal power series $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$.

Those isomorphic to the set of integrable (in various sense of definition of "integrable") functions on $(0,1)$, for instance, $L¹(0,1)$, with scalar part evaluated as $\operatorname{eval}(f)=\int_0^1 f(x) dx$. The identity function plays here a special role and corresponds to the umbra with moments $\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$, which we will denote $A$: $\operatorname{eval}(A^n)=\int_0^1 x^ndx=\frac1{n+1}$. A countable-dimensional restriction of this algebra is isomorphic to the set of sequences $a_k$ with element-wise operations and the scalar part (evaluation) is expressed via the regularized value of the series $\operatorname{eval}(a)=a_0+\operatorname{reg}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k+1}-a_k)$. In this representation, the aforementioned umbra corresponds to the identity sequence $A_k=k$: $\operatorname{eval}(A^n)=1+\operatorname{reg}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left((k+1)^n-k^n\right)=\frac1{n+1}$ via Dirichlet or Zeta regularization. This sequence-based representation can be denoted as $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Those isomorphic to the umbral calculus, with special element being Bernoulli umbra $B$ with moments being Bernoulli numbers $\operatorname{eval}(B^n)=B_n$.


Notice that the system 2 and system 3 are somehow inverse to each other as for analytic $f(x)$, $\operatorname{eval}(f(A+x))=\Delta D^{-1}f(x)$ and $\operatorname{eval}f(B+x)=D\Delta^{-1}f(x)$. Yet, the system 3 (umbral) is much less trivial than the others and connected with the Riemann hypothesis, it can be formulated as "All zeros of $\operatorname{eval}(B^z)$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ have the form of $\operatorname{eval}(B^{1/2+ix})$ or $\operatorname{eval}(B^{x})$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$".
So, my questions are:

Is there a set of distinguishing algebraic properties of these three systems that set them apart from other infinite-dimensional algebras and umbral calculi?
Can one extend the systems 2 and 3 to be of a proper class size, similar to the system 1?
Can these systems be combined together to form a unified algebra? For instance, the following should hold in the unified system: $\operatorname{eval}(f(A+B))=f(0)$.

